# Ansible - pip3 install fails

Tags: python, ansible, pip

I am trying to install Ansible on CentOS 7, and have Ansible configured to use Python 3. I've both Python2 and Python3 installed.

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# python --version
Python 2.7.5
[root@ansible1 ~]# python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

If I install Ansible using `yum install ansible`, the `ansible --version` command shows that Ansible is configured to use Python 2.7.5. I uninstall ansible (`yum remove ansible`);

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.10
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html:

> The easiest way to run /usr/bin/ansible under Python 3 is to install it with the Python3 version of pip. This will make the default /usr/bin/ansible run with Python3

I have version 9.0.3 of pip installed.

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Following Ansibles documentation, I issue `pip3 install ansible` to install Ansible using pip3.

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# pip3 install ansible
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting ansible
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/69/c8aef60ce070fe6872e27db65f588bd0ffe8892a980cd3f4d844d8b72152/ansible-2.9.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from jinja2->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography->ansible)
Installing collected packages: ansible
  Running setup.py install for ansible ... done
Successfully installed ansible-2.9.12
```

Here is the output of the `pip3 show ansible` command.

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# pip3 show ansible
Name: ansible
Version: 2.9.12
Summary: Radically simple IT automation
Home-page: https://ansible.com/
Author: Ansible, Inc.
Author-email: info@ansible.com
License: GPLv3+
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: jinja2, PyYAML, cryptography
```

However, the `ansible --version` command returns the following.

```
-bash: /bin/ansible: No such file or directory
```

Likewise, `/usr/bin/ansible --version`:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/ansible: No such file or directory
```

The `pip show ansible` command shows that the location is `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible`. This directory exists, and contains many files and folders, but no Ansible specific configuration files (e.g. ansible.cfg) or binary files (e.g. ansible) that can be used (best I can tell).

Comment: what says `ls -l /bin/ansible` -- maybe it's a dead link pointing nowhere, created maybe through a previous installation of ansible?

Comment: ls /bin/ansible (or /sbin/ansible, or /usr/bin/ansible) all return something like `ls: cannot access /bin/ansible: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bash [caches the paths to commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-hash), and if a command is relocated (as it appears to be in your case) then bash will not pick it up unless that cache is cleared.

You can clear `ansible` from the cache with:

```
hash -d ansible
```

Or clear the entire cache with:

```
hash -r
```

Comment: Amazing, that resolved it. That's going straight into my personal notes. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Any modification to `$PATH` will also clear the cache (since the cache contains paths found by searching `$PATH`), so I use `PATH=$PATH` which I find easier to remember.